# A programatically assigned formula is not updating

Tags: excel, vba

I'm assigning a formula to a column via a VBA subroutine.

The sub looks something like:

```
While curCell.Formula <> ""
    curCell.Formula = "=MATCH(RC[-20],"E:E",0)"
Wend
```

After running the subroutine the formula is correctly copied but all the cells show "#NAME?".  If I select a cell and hit enter then the formula is correctly calculated and the result is shown.

Automatic calculations are turned on.

Comment: What is the format of the cells after you enter them? I had mine formatted to text before, so I had to reformat them back to "General".

Comment: @Jon49 good idea, but the formatting is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a good idea to try to mix R1C1 and A1 notation in the same formula.
Try something like

```
Range("z1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(RC[-20],C5:C5,0)"
```

Comment: I think this is pretty much what was happening.  DO you know of any Microsoft link where they lay out this type of rule?